# Uncaught ReferenceError: parameter_name is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

Uncaught ReferenceError: province_name is not defined

I'm having this error and I don't know why, because I have used the same steps with other methods and everything is ok. What I want to do is to pass a parameter on a onclick function in venta.php from venta.js, and when the btn is clicked the info must be added on the page.

This is the code for venta.php

```
require_once "../modelos/Disponibilidad.php";
        $disponibilidad = new Disponibilidad();

        $rspta = $disponibilidad->listarDisponibilidadEstadoDisponible();
        $data = array();

        while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()) {
            $data[] = array(
                "0" => '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="agregarDetalleDisponibilidad(' . $reg->nombre_provincia . ')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
                "1" => $reg->nombre_provincia,
                "2" => $reg->ciudad,
                "3" => $reg->descripcion,
                "4" => $reg->fecha_disponible,
                "5" => $reg->hora_disponible,
                "6" => $reg->estado

            );
        }
```

Code for venta.js

```
function agregarDetalleDisponibilidad(nombreProvincia) {
    if (idDisponibilidad != "") {
        var filaDisponibilidad =
            '<tr class="filasDisponibilidad" id="disponibilidad' + contDisponibilidad + '">' +
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalleDisponibilidad(' + contDisponibilidad + ')">X</button></td>' +
            '<td><input type="hidden" name="iddisponibilidad[]" value="' + idDisponibilidad + '">' + nombreProvincia + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + nombreCiudad + '"></td>' +
            '<td>' + tipoVehiculo + '"></td>' +
            '<td>' + fechaDisponible + '"></td>' +
            '<td>' + horaDisponible + '"></td>' +
            '</tr>';
        contDisponibilidad++;
        detalleDisponibilidad++;
        $('#detalleSeleccionDisponibilidad').append(filaDisponibilidad);
    } else {
        alert("Error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos de la disponibilidad ");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see `province_name` at all anywhere.

Comment: I added it as an example for the error. for example Uncaught ReferenceError: Valencia is not defined. The province name is "nombreProvincia"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings inside of functions need to be quoted. Change your code from

```
"0" => '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="agregarDetalleDisponibilidad(' . $reg->nombre_provincia . ')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
```

to

```
"0" => '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="agregarDetalleDisponibilidad(\'' . $reg->nombre_provincia . '\')"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>',
```